# How render first node in views result in different view mode?

Tags: 7, views

Currently, I handle it by using `context`. before calling `views_embed_view`, I set a variable in `context` and in `node.tpl.php` at first result I unset this variable...

is there any better way to handle it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) in combination with Views. This allows you for example to choose a different view mode for each row or alternating view modes or whatever you want.

Comment: for each row? so can I render first row as full and other rows as teaser?

Comment: Yes, for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use node.tpl.php to theme something related to Views.

Instead, use one of the theme template files Views tells you about in 'Theme information' in Views UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an "attachment" view. [This is an article](http://www.phase2technology.com/node/418) where the author solved a similar problem to yours.

Comment: what is attachment views? I solved this by using context module. but I think its dirty way, please explain more

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to more information.

Comment: Could you include a summary of what reported in the linked article?

Answer (score 0):

I think in regular cases the best approach is to create an views block inside the specific view and adjust the delta for the block and the view accordingly (like mentioned in [this overlapping thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16871/3125)).

For more specific control you could also use the module [Views nodes split](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) as mentioned [in another answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16720/3125).